# Suggest tag synonyms when tags end up with identical descriptions

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

I just stumbled across the tags [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) and [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post). They have the same description, but are not marked as synonyms. It seems that detection of such pairs could be automated, perhaps when creating a tag, or editing the tag's description.

... As an added bonus, could someone with sufficient points add this synonym?

Related to this specific pair of tags: lots of people misuse `post` meaning "wordpress post". Does that mean this tag should be deleted or blacklisted? I suppose submitting lots of edits removing `post` from such questions would be frowned-upon, so what's the right way to tidy this up?

Comment: How many tags are there with an identical or near-identical excerpt?

Comment: No idea. There's a reason I suggest automating the process (humans are fairly bad at doing `n^2`-many string comparisons :P )

Comment: Clearly, someone should build a fancy NLP thing that finds synonymous tag descriptions and flags them for review. ;)